# D3 Google Sheet Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, google-sheets, cors

I've written a small piece of JS to feed numbers into my HTML on my website. It worked when I ran the files locally, but when I uploaded it to my hosting, Lithium, my D3 code is throwing this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12jMwpmqdbUUfcMHWg2GwGvu-d9BhaJOEsWjK1eoqHRc/pub?output=csv. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://alanhovorka.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I've read some of the answers on here, but they don't seem to directly address when D3 pulls in data from a Google Sheet published to the web as a CSV. I've seen mixed responses about whether CORS works with D3 and if I need to use tabletop. My knowledge of CORS is limited, but it seems like it would be the simplest the solution. Also, I've never been able to get tabletop to work and I've read concerns about its long-term viability.

Here's my JS with the spreadsheet call: 
The website is [alanhovorka.com](http://alanhovorka.com)

```
d3.csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12jMwpmqdbUUfcMHWg2GwGvu-d9BhaJOEsWjK1eoqHRc/pub?output=csv", function(error, data) {
    d3.select("#requests").selectAll('h1').data(data).append("h1").style("color", "#387284").text(function(d) {
        return d.rqt_count;
    });
    d3.select("#agencies").selectAll('h1').data(data).append("h1").style("color", "#387284").text(function(d) {
        return d.agency_cnt;
    });
    d3.select("#records").selectAll('h1').data(data).append("h1").style("color", "#387284").text(function(d) {
        return d.records_obt_cnt;
    });
    d3.select("#pages").selectAll('h1').data(data).append("h1").style("color", "#387284").text(function(d) {
        return d.pg_cnt;
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> My knowledgeof CORS is limited, but it seems like it would be the simplest the solution.

It isn't. You don't control Google's servers, so you can't add those headers to the response.

You'll need to either use a proxy or [get the data through the API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) instead.